# How do I make my phone fully customizable?

Tags: hardware, customization

Recently my friend1 who knows how do stuff with phones has made friend2s phone fully customizable. At least that's what he said. The other day friend2 made everything in his phone to show Hodor. Time, letters, applications, everything.
I asked my friend1 how he did it and he spoke about it but I remember only that he did some stuff, flashed friend2 phone a couple of times and **BOOM** done it.

I'm listing these if you need to know:

1. My phone is Samsung I8190 Galaxy S III min
2. Version 4.1.2
3. Has Kingroot
4. Has fx installed

If you need to know anything please ask me.

Sincerely,
Seagullman

Comment: After rooting you can install custom ROM.. and can customize functions.

Answer (score 1):

The Hodor trick is done using this [Hodor](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.germainz.hodor) Xposed module, which requires [Xposed framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer).

For a rooted device, installing Xposed is indeed a good way to customize without stepping into the realm of custom ROMs, but it comes at the usual risk of bootlooping and other problems. If you're only looking to do it for fun, and have no idea of how to recover from such failures, I advise you against it.